# php-fpm terminating and not restarting resulting in 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx, digital-ocean, fpm

I have a DigitalOcean droplet that hosts a Laravel app. For server management I use Laravel Forge and Envoyer (for zero downtime deployments).

I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway on my website.
I narrowed the problem down to php8.1-fpm terminating and not restarting.

Is php8.1-fpm supposed to terminate from time to time and restart? If so why is restarting not taking place?

Here are the logs from /var/log/php8.1-fpm.log file:

```
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:03] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 8 total children
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:05] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 9 total children
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:09] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 10 total children
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:13] WARNING: [pool www] child 172325, script '/home/forge/my-site-address.com/releases/20231010085401/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (60.698366 sec), terminating
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:13] WARNING: [pool www] child 171901, script '/home/forge/my-site-address.com/releases/20231010085401/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (68.674962 sec), terminating
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:13] WARNING: [pool www] child 172325 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 513.394876 seconds from start
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:13] NOTICE: [pool www] child 172536 started
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:14] WARNING: [pool www] child 171901 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1803.025691 seconds from start
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:14] NOTICE: [pool www] child 172537 started
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 172519, script '/home/forge/my-site-address.com/releases/20231010085401/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (74.734089 sec), terminating
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 172519 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 80.438516 seconds from start
[11-Oct-2023 00:31:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 172546 started
[11-Oct-2023 01:00:22] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[11-Oct-2023 01:00:23] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```